# Expectation of repeated number 3 times on dice

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, dice

Independent tosses of a loaded die with probabilities $p_i$
, $i$ = 1, ..., 6, are performed.

1. Let N denote the number of tosses until the initial outcome has occurred
   exactly 3 times. For instance, if the toss results are 4,3,4,5,1,6,2,4 then
   N = 8. Find E(N).
2. Find the expected number of tosses needed until both 1 and 6 appeared.
   Compute it when the die is fair.

Comment: @Mark Fischler So far, Y = 1 if I get a number that has been rolled before, and Y = 0 if I get a new number.

E(X) = p(E(X)|Y=1) + (1-p)(E(X)|Y=0) = this is where I get confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected number of rolls until you get number $i$ once is $\frac1{p_i}$.  So the answer to problem 1, where you need to roll whatever number comes up first two more times, is 
$$
\sum_i p_i \left(1+2\frac1{p_i}\right) = \sum_i p_i + \sum_i 2\frac{p_i}{p_i} = 1 + 2\sum_{i=1}^6 1 = 13
$$

For the second one, first either 1 or 6 has to appear, then the other.  So we start with the expectation for the combined probabilities, then add the *weighted* average of the expectation for the individual probabilities. So we have
$$
\frac1{p_1+p_6} + \frac{p_1}{p_1+p_6}\frac1{p_6} + \frac{p_6}{p_1+p_6}\frac1{p_1} = \frac{p_1p_6+p_1^2+p_6^2}{(p_1+p_6)p_1p_6}
$$
When the die is fair, this works out to be $9$

Comment: how did you get that for a fair dice, it works out to 9 in the second part?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. Thank you!